# Get last / delimited value from Dataframe column in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get the last string after '/'.

The column can look like this: *"lala/mae.da/rg1/zzzzz"* (not necessary only 3 /), and I'd like to return: *zzzzz*

In SQL and Python it's very easy, but I would like to know if there is a way to do it in PySpark.

Solving it in Python:

```
original_string = "lala/mae.da/rg1/zzzzz"
last_char_index = original_string.rfind("/")
new_string = original_string[last_char_index+1:]
```

or directly:

```
new_string = original_string.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
```

And in SQL:

```
RIGHT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(MyColumn))-1)
```

For PySpark I was thinking something like this:

```
df = df.select(col("MyColumn").rsplit('/', 1)[1])
```

but I get the following error: *TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable* and I am not even sure Spark allows me to do rsplit at all.

Do you have any suggestion on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = pd.DataFrame({"MyColumn": ["lala/mae.da/rg1/zzzzz", "fefe", "fe/fe/frs/fs/fe32/4"]})

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.show(truncate=False)

# output
+---------------------+
|MyColumn             |
+---------------------+
|lala/mae.da/rg1/zzzzz|
|fefe                 |
|fe/fe/frs/fs/fe32/4  |
+---------------------+
```

```
(
    df
    .withColumn("NewCol", 
                F.split("MyColumn", "/")
               )
    .withColumn("NewCol", F.col("Newcol")[F.size("NewCol") -1])
    .show()
)

# output
+--------------------+------+
|            MyColumn|NewCol|
+--------------------+------+
|lala/mae.da/rg1/z...| zzzzz|
|                fefe|  fefe|
| fe/fe/frs/fs/fe32/4|     4|
+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was trying to achieve!!

Answer (score 3):

Adding another solution even though @Pav3k's answer is great. [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#element_at) which  gets an item at specific position out of a list:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('my_col_split', F.split(df['MyColumn'], '/'))\
                          .select('MyColumn',F.element_at(F.col('my_col_split'), -1).alias('rsplit')
                                 )

>>> df.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+------+
|MyColumn             |rsplit|
+---------------------+------+
|lala/mae.da/rg1/zzzzz|zzzzz |
|fefe                 |fefe  |
|fe/fe/frs/fs/fe32/4  |4     |
+---------------------+------+
```

Pav3k's `DF` used.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use [`split` built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) to split your string then use [`element_at` built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html) to get the last element of your obtained array, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select(F.element_at(F.split(F.col("MyColumn"), '/'), -1))
```

Comment: this also works, thank you!